# preg_replace, value comes out as $1.. But used modifer "e"

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have tried to make a bbCode system with preg_replace, which runs a function, but for some reason the output is just $1, even trough I have added the 'e' modifer.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Source code:

```
            function bbcode($value){
                $pattern[0] = "/\{register\}(.*?)\{\/register\}/sie";
                $replace[0] = register('$1'); //"<pre>$1</pre>";
                $bbcoded = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $value);
                return $bbcoded;
            }

            function register($var) {
                echo $var;
            }

            $content = '
                {b}text{/b}
                {register}
                    "register" = "setting",
                    "name" = "title",
                    "order" = "1"
                {/register}
                some text
                {register}
                    "register" = "setting",
                    "name" = "url",
                    "order" = "3"
                {/register}
                some more {b}t{/b}e{b}xt{/b}
                {register}
                    "register" = "setting",
                    "name" = "description",
                    "order" = "2"
                {/register}
                text text
            ';

            $content = bbcode($content);
```

See it in action: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/08459c4fec1919e6089d3849e154ba7a83900fd7

Comment: Quote your function name: `$replace[0] = 'register("$1")';` else register will be called before preg_replace itself. Note: modifier e is deprecated, you should avoid it and replace it by preg_replace_callback

Comment: Do not use the `e` modifier, ever. Use `preg_replace_callback()` instead. No exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

You should use [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://www.php.net/preg_replace_callback) instead:

```
 $pattern = "/\{register\}(.*?)\{\/register\}/si"; // NO /e modifier!
 $bbcoded = preg_replace_callback($pattern, 'register', $value);

 function register($var) 
 {
     // $var[0] is the whole match
     // $var[1] is the part between {register} and {/register}

     // whatever you return here will be the replacement string
     return $var[0];
 }
```

The second parameter to `preg_replace_callback()` is a [callable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php) that runs at every match found and its return value is used as the replacement.

**Update**

The syntax for `/e` replacement would be this btw (the whole thing should be a string):

```
$bbcoded = preg_replace_callback($pattern, "register('$1')", $value);
```

Answer (score 1):

Basic php syntax...

```
            $replace[0] = register("$1"); //"<pre>$1</pre>";
                                   ^--^--
```

strings using `'` for quotes do not interpolate variables. As well, your `register()` function is **ECHOING** the value you pass in. As such, your `$register[0]` is going to be the return value of the register function, which will be null - register isn't returning anything.

Comment: Thanks, but without luck -.-